# Find Duplicate Values In Excel and Export Rows to another sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA scripts... What I'm trying to do is:

- check column for duplicate values in MS Excel file
- If duplicates are present, then copy rows containing duplicate values to another worksheet...

For example I have a sheet1 with content:

[image: original text]

I want to go through the contents in column A and export rows containing duplicate values in column A to new sheet :

[image: expected text in new sheet]

after searching and editing some VBA Scripts i came up with this code:

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()

Dim wstSource As Worksheet, _
    wstOutput As Worksheet
Dim rngCell As Range, _
    rngMyData As Range
Dim lngMyRow As Long

Set wstSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wstOutput = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set rngMyData = wstSource.Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each rngCell In rngMyData
    If Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & rngMyData.Address & "," & rngCell.Address & ")") > 1 Then
        lngMyRow = wstOutput.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wstSource.Range("A" & rngCell.Row & ":D" & rngCell.Row).Copy _
            Destination:=wstOutput.Range("A" & lngMyRow & ":D" & lngMyRow)
    End If
Next rngCell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Is this correct code? can it be optimized to be faster?**

I have 80.000 records to go through with it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**edit**: added another alternative code (see "2nd code"), which should be much, much faster

try these optimization

1st code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterAndCopy()

Dim wstSource As Worksheet, _
    wstOutput As Worksheet
Dim rngMyData As Range, _
    helperRng As Range

Set wstSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wstOutput = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With wstSource
    Set rngMyData = .Range("A1:D" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
Set helperRng = rngMyData.Offset(, rngMyData.Columns.Count + 1).Resize(, 1)

With helperRng
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=if(countif(C1,RC1)>1,"""",1)"
    .Value = .Value
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wstOutput.Cells(1, 1)
    .ClearContents
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

"2nd code"

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterAndCopy2()

Dim wstSource As Worksheet, _
    wstOutput As Worksheet
Dim rngMyData As Range, _
    helperRng As Range, _
    unionRng As Range
Dim i As Long, iOld As Long

Set wstSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wstOutput = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
With wstSource
    Set rngMyData = .Range("A1:D" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With

With rngMyData
    Set helperRng = .Offset(, rngMyData.Columns.Count - 1).Resize(, 1)
    Set unionRng = .Cells(1000, 1000) 'set a "helper" cell to be used with Union method, to prevent it from failing the first time
End With

With helperRng
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=row()" 'mark rows with ad ascending number (its own row number)
    .Value = .Value
End With

With rngMyData.Resize(, rngMyData.Columns.Count + 1) 'enclose "helper" column
    .Sort key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo ' sort data to have all same columnA values grouped one after another
    i = .Rows(1).Row 'start loop from data first row
    Do While i < .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
        iOld = i 'set current row as starting row
        Do While .Cells(iOld + 1, 1) = .Cells(iOld, 1) 'loop till first cell with different value
            iOld = iOld + 1
        Loop

        If iOld - i > 0 Then Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, .Cells(i, 1).Resize(iOld - i + 1)) 'if more than one cell found with "current" value, then add them to "UnionRng" range
        i = iOld + 1
    Loop
    Intersect(unionRng, rngMyData).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wstOutput.Cells(1, 1) 'get rid of the "helper" cell via Intersect method
    wstOutput.Columns(helperRng.Column).Clear 'delete "Helper" column pasted in wstOutput sheet
    .Sort key1:=.Columns(4), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo ' sort data in wstSource back
End With
helperRng.Clear 'delete "helper" column, not needed anymore

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: see edited answer: I added a "2nd code" that in my test proved much faster

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do it. To make it more simpler I tried changing you loop only. PFB the changed code -

```
For Each rngCell In rngMyData
'''    If Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & rngMyData.Address & "," & rngCell.Address & ")") > 1 Then
'''        lngMyRow = wstOutput.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
'''        wstSource.Range("A" & rngCell.Row & ":D" & rngCell.Row).Copy _
'''            Destination:=wstOutput.Range("A" & lngMyRow & ":D" & lngMyRow)
'''    End If

   If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngMyData, rngCell.Value) > 1 Then

        wstOutput.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value = rngCell.EntireRow.Value

   End If


Next rngCell
```