# VBA find duplicates from 2nd column and export to second row

Tags: vba, excel

I found a very good example of what I need to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693500/find-duplicate-values-in-excel-and-export-rows-to-another-sheet-using-vba) but the duplicates that I have to find are in the 2nd column and also I have to paste in the 'duplicate' worksheet starting from the 2nd row.

For example, in the Source worksheet I have the following

```
Class Name   Age
A     John   10
A     Maria  11
A     John   12
B     John   15
B     Andy   10
B     John   16
```

And in the Duplicate worksheet I want to get the the duplicates as follows

```
Class Name   Age
A     John   10
A     John   12
B     John   15
B     John   16
```

How can I change this code to achieve this:

```
Dim wstSource As Worksheet, _
    wstOutput As Worksheet
Dim rngMyData As Range, _
    helperRng As Range

Set wstSource = Worksheets("Source")
Set wstOutput = Worksheets("Duplicates")

With wstSource
    Set rngMyData = .Range("A1:AQ" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
Set helperRng = rngMyData.Offset(, rngMyData.Columns.Count + 1).Resize(, 1)

With helperRng
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=if(countif(C1,RC1)>1,"""",1)"
    .Value = .Value
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wstOutput.Cells(1, 1)
    .ClearContents
End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see commented lines

```
Dim wstSource As Worksheet, _
    wstOutput As Worksheet
Dim rngMyData As Range, _
    helperRng As Range

Set wstSource = Worksheets("Source")
Set wstOutput = Worksheets("Duplicates")

With wstSource
    Set rngMyData = .Range("A1:AQ" & .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).row)
End With
Set helperRng = rngMyData.Offset(, rngMyData.Columns.count + 1).Resize(, 1)

With helperRng
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=if(countif(C2,RC2)>1,"""",1)" '<--| change references to column 2
    .Value = .Value
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wstOutput.Cells(2, 1) '<--| start pasting from rew 2
    .ClearContents
End With
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks.